# How to make justified masonry-like gallery

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

Tried masonry and several other popular jquery plugins, but all aligned to left/right or center and can not be justified.
Tried to look deeper in masonry code to setup width of gallery container the same as parent offset width, but without luck.
The main idea is that I don't know the exact size and assign it with css to have a justified grid.

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a fast jquery plugin some time ago for this.

You should check it out, maybe it could give you a kickstart.

https://github.com/floo51/jquery-bricks

Comment: Thanks, starred it and will try to dig deeper :)

Comment: Alright, don't hesitate to submit a pull request if you correct/improve anything !